# Change alignment and remove spaces in between tr and td

Tags: html, css

Hi am designing a form where I have a table and inside that table, I have a nested table too.
Let me show you the code,

```
<table class="quiz-template-table">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="title">Header Text</td>
           <td class="title-data">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="txt01"/>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table id="tblHeaderPosition">
               <tr class="header-position">
                  <td colspan="2">Specify Position And Styles</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="position members">
                  <td>Position </td>
                  <td>
                     <select name="Position">
                       <option value="Top-Left">Top-Left</option>
                       <option value="Top-Center">Top-Center</option>
                       <option value="Top-Right">Top-Right</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Left">Middle-Left</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Center">Middle-Center</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Right">Middle-Right</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Left">Bottom-Left</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Center">Bottom-Center</option>
                       <option value="Middle-Right">Bottom-Right</option>
                     </select>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr class="position members">
                    <td>Font Name</td>
                     <td>
                        <select name="Font">
                            <option value="1">Font-1</option>
                            <option value="2">Font-2</option>
                            <option value="3">Font-3</option>
                            <option value="4">Font-4</option>
                            <option value="5">Font-5</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr class="position members">
                     <td>Font Style</td>
                       <td style="width: 2%">
                          <select name="Font-Style">
                              <option value="bold">Bold</option>
                              <option value="italics">Italics</option>
                              <option value="italics">Combine</option>
                           </select>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
        </table>
            </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Sub Header Text</td>
                <td class="title-data">
                   <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt02"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Subject</td>
                <td class="title-data">
                    <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt03" />
                </td>
             </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, If I remove the nested table then all the alignment and spacing between `<td>` s are displaying as expected

let me show you that,

[image]

Now If I put the nested table then, there are some spaces are there in between them,

[image]

as you could see there are alot of spaces between these `<td>` s are there and also ,

If you hide the nested table then,

[image]

as you could see there are some spaces in between **Specify Position and styles** and **Subheader Text**..

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Please also note that, I have posted [this problem over here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4ym7gob/).
Please have a look at it and it would be nice If I get any solution regarding this.

Update :

[image]

As You could see there is a huge gap between label and textbox

[image]

I want to minimize the gap just like this
Thanks and Regards

Comment: use `col-span` for solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very much clear with your question but are looking for something like this:

```js
$('.header-position').click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
   $(this).nextUntil('tr.header-position')
   .find('td')
   .parent()
   .find('td > div')
   .slideDown("fast", function () {
    var $set = $(this);
    $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
   });
   $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
  } else {
   $(this).nextUntil('tr.header-position')
   .find('td')
   .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
   .parent()
   .find('td > div')
   .slideUp("fast");
   $(this).addClass("collapsed");
  }
 });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.title{
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .quiz-template-table td {
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
 }


 .header-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .members {
  font-family: helvetica;
 }
 tr.header-position.collapsed ~ .members > td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table class="quiz-template-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Header Text</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt01"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
    <table id="tblHeaderPosition">
     <tr class="header-position">
      <td colspan="2">Specify Position And Styles</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Position </td>
      <td>
       <select name="Position">
        <option value="Top-Left">Top-Left</option>
        <option value="Top-Center">Top-Center</option>
        <option value="Top-Right">Top-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Middle-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Middle-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Middle-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Bottom-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Bottom-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Bottom-Right</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Font Name</td>
      <td>
       <select name="Font">
        <option value="Top-Left">Top-Left</option>
        <option value="Top-Center">Top-Center</option>
        <option value="Top-Right">Top-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Middle-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Middle-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Middle-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Bottom-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Bottom-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Bottom-Right</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Font Style</td>
      <td style="width: 2%">
       <select name="Font-Style">
        <option value="bold">Bold</option>
        <option value="italics">Italics</option>
        <option value="italics">Combine</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Sub Header Text</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt02"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Subject</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt03" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your reply but as I mentioned above putting nested table created a gap between <td> Text</td> <td> and <input type="text" ... /> I want to remove that gap if possible. Updated my question too. Please have a look at the question's Update section :)

Comment: This same thing was there in the answer below by @sam, he just didn't include the snippet and he answered in short form.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using css. Please review my code carefully.
I'm just added this css

```
tr.header-position.collapsed ~ .members > td {padding: 0;  border: 0;}
```

When your collapsed is open then we need to hide padding and border. Let me know if you have further clarification.

```js
 $('.header-position').click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
   $(this).nextUntil('tr.header-position')
   .find('td')
   .parent()
   .find('td > div')
   .slideDown("fast", function () {
    var $set = $(this);
    $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
   });
   $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
  } else {
   $(this).nextUntil('tr.header-position')
   .find('td')
   .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
   .parent()
   .find('td > div')
   .slideUp("fast");
   $(this).addClass("collapsed");
  }
 });
```

```css
 .title{
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .quiz-template-table td {
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
 }


 .header-position {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .members {
  font-family: helvetica;
 }
 tr.header-position.collapsed ~ .members > td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table class="quiz-template-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Header Text</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt01"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="tblHeaderPosition">
     <tr class="header-position">
      <td colspan="2">Specify Position And Styles</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Position </td>
      <td>
       <select name="Position">
        <option value="Top-Left">Top-Left</option>
        <option value="Top-Center">Top-Center</option>
        <option value="Top-Right">Top-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Middle-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Middle-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Middle-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Bottom-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Bottom-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Bottom-Right</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Font Name</td>
      <td>
       <select name="Font">
        <option value="Top-Left">Top-Left</option>
        <option value="Top-Center">Top-Center</option>
        <option value="Top-Right">Top-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Middle-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Middle-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Middle-Right</option>
        <option value="Middle-Left">Bottom-Left</option>
        <option value="Middle-Center">Bottom-Center</option>
        <option value="Middle-Right">Bottom-Right</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="position members">
      <td>Font Style</td>
      <td style="width: 2%">
       <select name="Font-Style">
        <option value="bold">Bold</option>
        <option value="italics">Italics</option>
        <option value="italics">Combine</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Sub Header Text</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt02"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="title">Subject</td>
   <td class="title-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="txt03" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your solution, but there is another problem that I have mentioned above, inserting nested table created a lot of spaces between <td> s i.e in between label and input box . I want to remove those spaces , can I do that?

Comment: Sir I have tested your code localy, tr.header-position.collapsed ~ .members > td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
} this code has done the trick but still cant able to figure out why there are still spaces in between <td> s.

Comment: See there are still spaces in between Header Text label and corresponding text box.

Comment: For the spacing you need to add one more css : table#tblHeaderPosition {
    border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0;}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td colspan="2">
            <table id="tblHeaderPosition" >
                  <tr class="header-position"></tr></table></td>
```

Where you are starting new table there in the `td` tag, add `colspan=2`.